# Error in Rails Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I used to follow [coderwall tutorial in ajax](https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy) but I got ActionController::UnknownFormat when I open to new tab the following link <%= link_to 'Link Name', fetch_items_path(:cat_id => cat.id), :remote => true %>. What's wrong with this? Thanks!

In additional, when I click the link it doesn't respond to anything.

Here is the

Controller:

```
def from_category
  @selected = Item.find(params[:cat_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Views

index.html.erb

`<%= link_to 'Link Name', fetch_items_path(:cat_id => cat.id), :remote => true %>`

_items_list.html.erb

```
<% items.each do |item| %>
  <div class="item_box">
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

item_grid.html.erb

```
<div>
  <div id="items_grid" >
    <%= render partial: 'items_list', locals: {items: items}  %>
  </div>
</div>
```

from_category.js.erb

```
$("#items_grid").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items_list', locals: { items: @selected } ) %>");
```

Comment: what about the route.rb?

Comment: I forgot to include my route, here it is: get "/fetch_items" => 'items#from_category', as: 'fetch_items', I guess there is something with my controller with "format.js". I've tried to add format.html but it is looking for a html file for it and the behavior I want is to trigger the js.erb.

Comment: I look your partial file _items.list.html.erb instead of _items_list.html.erb? How about error in console in server and console browser?

Comment: Sorry _items.list.html.erb was a typo error. I modified it see above.

Comment: I see based on your image. You try to access you page in url but it is ajax so you can't access via url. If you want to try you have to add format.html. To run your ajax, you have to click your link. Remember, you have to restart server if you add a routes for you ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing, I've got the wrong part of the code. It's regarding to routing.

Instead:

`get "/fetch_items" => 'items#from_category', as: 'fetch_items'`

I changed to:

`get "fetch_items"`

and its working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

The likelihood is that you're sending a `json` request, which isn't covered by your `respond_to` block.

You can see this by doing the following:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json
  format.js
end
```

Alternatively, you could also try:

```
<%= link_to 'Link Name', fetch_items_path(:cat_id => cat.id), remote: true, format: :js %>
```

If either of these work, it essentially means you're sending a JSON request, which won't be handled. The patches above should resolve it if it is the case.

--

Secondly, when you mention

> "I open to new tab"

You realize that Ajax isn't meant to work synchronously, right? This means that it's not meant to load "in order" of the entire page. It has to be loaded along-side the page itself. To do this, you need to invoke it from the page onto which it has been embedded.

--

Finally, you should be aware of the `JS console` in your browser.

For Chrome and Firefox, you can access this by right-clicking, selecting "Inspect Element". This will bring up the "Developer Console", from which you'll be able to see what's happening with the javascript:

[image]

Now, the importance of this for your case is simple. You mention "nothing happens" when you click the link. There are several potentialities for this:

- You don't have [`jquery-ujs`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) enabled (which is what Rails uses to get the likes of `remote` working
- You've got an error on your server preventing the script from firing.

Either way, you'll be able to see what's going on by clicking onto the Developer Console and examining the `networking` tab. Notice when you click the link - does it create a new request? If not, you'll have to add the `jquery-ujs` gem to your Application.js file, else there's an issue with the script on the server.

Comment: Hi @Rich Peck, I've tried both but still I've got the following: ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnkwonwFormat): app/controllers/items_controller.rb:13:in `from_category`

Comment: Can you post your Rails console and your JS console log for the request?

Comment: Hi @Rich Peck, I added the log and what happened when I open the link to new tab.

Comment: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/RGNrm.png] and here is what happened when I open the "Link Name" to new tab
[http://i.stack.imgur.com/HaE1b.png]

Comment: Don't open your link in a new tab, because the request it sends will be different from the ajax one. You need to open your `network` tab, find there your broken request (usually it will be highlighted red, this one http://i.stack.imgur.com/RGNrm.png), click on it and select `Preview` tab on the right, you should be able to see an actual error.

Comment: Or you can go and just check `development.log` for other errors.

Comment: Yes, I checked the development.log and this is the issue: ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnkwonwFormat): app/controllers/items_controller.rb:13:in from_category